# Key Error when attempting to query AWS Redshift using `TABLESAMPLE`

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to query a table on AWS Redshift Cluster using Python within jupyter notebook. I'd like to randomly sample rows from the result set and am using `TABLESAMPLE`. However, i keep running into `Key Error`

```
import pandas as pd
import redshift_connector


conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    
     host=os.environ['host'],
     database=os.environ['database'],
     port=int(os.environ['port']),
     user=os.environ['user'],
     password=os.environ['password']
     
  )
  
print(conn)


cursor = conn.cursor()
print(cursor)

cursor.execute(
               """
               SELECT * 
               FROM tbl1 
               WHERE type = 'xxx'
               AND created_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
               AND created_at <= '2022-12-31 00:00:00'
               TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10);
               """ 
              )

df = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
df.columns = field_names`
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redshift_connector/core.py:1631, in Connection.execute(self, cursor, operation, vals)
   1630 try:
-> 1631     ps = cache["ps"][key]
   1632     cursor.ps = ps

KeyError: ("\n               SELECT * \n               FROM pmf  \n               WHERE event_type = 'load'\n               AND created_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' \n               AND created_at <= '2022-12-31 00:00:00'\n               TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10);\n               ", ())

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redshift_connector/core.py:1701, in Connection.execute(self, cursor, operation, vals)
   1698     else:
   1699         raise e
-> 1701 self.handle_messages(cursor)
   1703 # We've got row_desc that allows us to identify what we're
   1704 # going to get back from this statement.
   1705 output_fc = tuple(self.redshift_types[f["type_oid"]][0] for f in ps["row_desc"])

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redshift_connector/core.py:1969, in Connection.handle_messages(self, cursor)
   1966     self.message_types[code](self._read(data_len - 4), cursor)
   1968 if self.error is not None:
-> 1969     raise self.error

ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'C': '42601', 'M': 'syntax error at or near "TABLESAMPLE"', 'P': '220', 'F': '/home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/parser/parser_scan.l', 'L': '732', 'R': 'yyerror'}
```

```
cursor.execute(
               """
               SELECT * 
               FROM tbl1 
               WHERE type = 'xxx'
               AND created_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
               AND created_at <= '2022-12-31 00:00:00'
               TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10);
               """ 
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the way `TABLESAMPLE` works, when using the keyword the WHERE condition needs to be after the `TABLESAMPLE` clause.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10)
WHERE type = 'xxx'
AND created_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND created_at <= '2022-12-31 00:00:00';
```

Strange this is not mentioned on the Redshift documentation page. It's a bit more understandable from the [Postgres Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) as Redshift is a flavour of Postgres.

Seems that Redshift doesn't currently support the `TABLESAMPLE`, you can try the below alternative

```
select * from (
  select *, random() as sample 
  from tbl1
WHERE type = 'xxx'
AND created_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND created_at <= '2022-12-31 00:00:00') as samp
where sample < .01; -- return 1% of rows
```

Comment: I tried using `TABLESAMPLE` after the `FROM` clause but still get an error. `ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'C': '42601', 'M': 'syntax error at or near "SYSTEM"', 'P': '80', 'F': '/home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/parser/parser_scan.l', 'L': '732', 'R': 'yyerror'}`

Comment: @kll seems that Redshift doesn't currently support `TABLESAMPLE`, I have updated the query with an alternative approach.